# Integration in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I want to integrate exp(-x) from 0 to 100000 by using integrate function in R. However I find the answer to be 2.061453e-45 which is almost 0 (zero). The true answer would be 1-exp(-100000) which is almost 1. How do I carry out this integration using integrate function in R to get close to the correct solution?

The following is the R code used

```
ab<-function(x) { return(exp(-x)) }
integrate(ab,0,100000)$value
```

The output is

```
 2.061453e-45
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code you used to perform the integration?

Comment: @Aziz 

ab<-function(x)
{
  return(exp(-x))
}
integrate(ab,0,100000)$value

Comment: @Onyambu actually, I want to use integrate function. The issue i have raised here it is a subpart of a bigger problem. I just want to see the working criteria of integrate function.

Comment: The documentation for integrate counsels you to use Inf not a large number if you want the integral over an infinite interval. Do you want to calculate such an integral?

Comment: @Hugh
Yes, I understand your point. But can you please tell me that if somebody asks me to integrate $exp(-x)$  over this range (0, 100000), do i replace 100000 by Inf ? How do I know whether the upper-limit is to be replaced with Inf for any given integrable function?

Comment: @Tubai : You have to look at the properties of the function you're integrating. The function at x=100000 is tiny, and it keeps decreasing as x increases. Therefore, the integration from 0 to 100000 is almost equal to the integration from 0 to Infinity. In other words, the difference between the two (which is the integration from 100000 to infinity) is almost zero.

Comment: @ Aziz:
Even though if I integrate from 0 to 100000 and 100000 to Inf separately, I get outputs 0 in both the cases. Therefore if I add them it gives me the whole integration 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tubai: That is correct. It is because the numerical integration method does not work correctly for this particular example when you integrate from 0 to 100000. If you want to keep your boundaries and not use infinite, you can basically integrate the function from 0 to 100, and from 100 to 100000 separately. You will see that 0-100 will produce 1 and the other interval will produce 0, the sum of them (which is the integral from 0 to 100000) is 1.

Comment: @Aziz:
Thank you. This function seems to be very much unpredictable. Works for few function and does not work for others.

Answer (score 5):

This is a limitation of the numerical integration method used in R over large intervals. The [documentation of the `integrate` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/integrate) states that:

> **When integrating over infinite intervals do so explicitly, rather than just using a large number as the endpoint**. This increases the chance of a correct answer -- any function whose integral over an infinite interval is finite must be near zero for most of that interval.

Because the function `exp(-x)` is very close to zero at `x=100000` (actual value is approx. `3.56 × 10^-43430`), and because the function is decreasing, getting closer and closer to zero, you can safely integrate the function to infinity,

```
integrate( ab , 0 , Inf)
```

and you will get the correct result,

```
1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an *addition* to the good answer of @Aziz.

One of the parameters to `integrate` is

> subdivisions: the number of subintervals produced in the subdivision process.

The default value is 100. I.e. the function spreads out 100 points between 0 and 100000. This will radically undersample the points that matter - the points near x=0. If you are having a problem with integrating to infinity, you could break the integral up into smaller segments - from 0 to 10, 10 to 20, and 20 to 100000 - forcing heavier sampling near x=0.

```
> integrate(ab,0,10)$value 
[1] 0.9999546
> integrate(ab,10,20)$value
[1] 4.539787e-05
> integrate(ab,20,100000)$value
[1] 4.341375e-54
> 
> integrate(ab,0,10)$value + integrate(ab,10,20)$value + integrate(ab,20,100000)$value
[1] 1
```